# how to store outlook body text phone number (or) selected area in sql server using asp.net outlook add ons?

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-4.0, outlook-addin, outlook-2007

i am using windows application **OutlookAddIn1**(office-2007) in VS2010, now my inbox have some mails and each mail have phone numbers , now my task is select the phone number and click the mouse right click , i have save text or save number option will appear how it is possible and select that option store that text into sql server2008 database table pls help my any one have idea about that topics , pls give any idea it is very urgent task

Thank u
hemanth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 private void savenumbers()
        {
            try
            {
                Outlook.Application oApp;
                Outlook.Explorer oExp;
                Outlook.Selection oSel;
                object oItem;
                long i;
                // TODO: On Error GoTo Warning!!!: The statement is not translatable
                oApp = new Outlook.Application();
                oExp = oApp.ActiveExplorer();
                oSel = oExp.Selection;
                if ((oSel.Count == 0))
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Nothing selected");
                    return;
                }
                for (i = 1; i <= oSel.Count; i++)
                {
                    oItem = oSel[i];

                    DisplayMessage(oItem);
                }
            }


            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
        public int outlooksavenumber(string testcopy)
        {

            int ReturnValue = 0;
            ReturnValue = SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(LITRMSConnection, "usp_Outlooksavenumbers",
                                                                        new SqlParameter("@testcopy", testcopy));

            return ReturnValue;
        }

        void DisplayMessage(object oItem)
        {
            //Outlook.MailItem oMailItem;
            Outlook.MailItem oMail = (Outlook.MailItem)oItem;
            //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(oMail.Subject);
            //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(oMail.Body);
            string body = oMail.Body;
            Outlook.Inspector inspector = oMail.GetInspector;

            // Obtain the Word.Document object from the Inspector object
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document)inspector.WordEditor;

            // Copy the selected objects
            string testcopy = "";
            testcopy = document.Application.Selection.Text;

            outlooksavenumber(testcopy);
        }
```